# When I am running program with the help of appium on eclipse i am getting session not created error

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I Have installed appium, android visual studio and also i have set the path in env varibales, now when i am running my fist sample program on eclipse then it is giving me below error :

```
[TestNG] Running:
  C:\Users\Akash Srivastava\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse-1729078009\testng-customsuite.xml

FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeClass setUp
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. 
  (Original error: Could not find adb. Please set the ANDROID_HOME 
   environment variable with the Android SDK root directory path.) 
  (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 433 milliseconds
```

Can anyone please help me what could have gone wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above issue got resolved since the package name which i am using for calculator app can be different for different devices and currently i was testing the calculator app on Sony that's why it wasn't working but when i tried with google mobile it got worked and when i researched about this issue i found out the above answer.